# How to show a list of belongs in relational data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two model like this:

User:

```
id - username
```

Image:

```
id - img - user_id
```

each user has many images. so it sounds I should use `hasMany` relation .

I know how can I use if I have a list of users. now how can I show a list of images by usernames :

list of images :

```
img - username
```

in `User` model :

```
  public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }
```

in `Image` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more "laravel-way" solution for getting users with their images will be something like:

```
$users = App\User::with('image')->get();
```

This will return a collection of users with their images. From then, you can loop through the users and show images like this (in your view):

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <ul>
        @foreach($user->images as $image)
        <li>{{ $image }}</li>
        @endforeach
    <ul>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('images', 'images.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->orderBy('users.username')
            ->groupBy('users.username')
            ->get();
```

Ok Then Try This:

```
$users = App\User::all();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $temp = App\UserImage::where('userId',$user->id)->get();
            $user['images'] = $temp;
        }
        return $users;
```

Comment: I don't want to use join.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian I have edited my answer. Please check and try.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the user hasMany images, for naming convention make the relation `images()` in user model.
then, this will give all the username with their images.

```
$users=User::with('images')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
   print_r($user->username);
   foreach($user->images as $image)
   {
     print_r($image);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This brings in the Image model to your user query. It groups the results by user.

```
$userImages = User::with('image')->groupBy('id')->get();
```

Since you have User and Images pulled up, you can query 'id', 'username', 'img_id', or 'img' fields with id and user_id linking the two.

This is the user.

```
     $userImages ->id->username
```

This returns the images by user

```
    foreach($userImages as $userImage)
{
  $userImage->image->user_id->img;
}
```